# Neo4j Uniquness on update unique index value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The

uniqueness=create_or_fail

works great when creating a new node since it throws a 4xx response if a duplicate index key/value already exists.

However, if the node already exists and indexed and the indexed value needs to be updated, there is no way (that i am aware of) to update the value and fail if the new value already exists. That is because the Add Node to Index REST call does not throw a 4xx response if the new value already exists. as far as i can see the add node to index does not even participate in Uniqueness on indexes.

One solution is to delete the node and re-add it but this is not easy since all the other indexes and relationships on this node would have to be recreated.

another solution would be to add the Uniqueness parameter to the Add Node to Index REST call
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.M05/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-add-node-to-index

any other ideas on this?

thanks

Comment: Usually uniqueness parameters are not updated. What is your concrete usecase? You can use the put-if-absent semantics of the rest-api-index and if that succeeds remove the old value for this node from the index.

Comment: if you have a unique index on a user's email address and the user updates their address, for example. in this case you would not want to create a new user node because of all of the existing relationships would have to be recreated.  What would be good is to have the same uniqueness parameter on the insert into index call.  this would return a 200 on success and a 4xx on conflict.  if this succeeds the next command in the batch would be a remove from index. So to your point, this would not be an update. it is a insert and delete of the index value and done in a batch transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I happened up on this question and here's what I figured out for a work-around.

During an update do as follows in a REST batch:

1. Delete all of node's index entries for the desired index
2. Create a new node using CreateOrFail on the desired index, except instead of using your normal properties just use a dummy property such as `DeleteMe=true`
3. Add the node to the desired index because if it got this far the previous step succeeded
4. Update node's properties
5. Use a Cypher statement to delete the dummy node Ex:

   `START n=node:index_name(index_key={value}) WHERE (n.DeleteMe!)=true DELETE n`